# Need example : D7 + XPath parser to import (mediawiki) XML - xpath parser settings?

Tags: 7, feeds

I've installed XPath/Feeds/D7, but I don't know how to configure XPath parser settings.

Maybe someone can help me to set it right.

I just want to inject `<title>` and `<text xml:space="preserve">` to my node.

I need help to configure my XPath Parser settings : admin/structure/feeds/edit/my_import/settings/FeedsXPathParserXML

I've the following XML structure :

```
<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.3/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.3/ http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.3.xsd" version="0.3" xml:lang="fr">
  <siteinfo>
    <sitename>Site Name</sitename>
    <base>http://domain.net/index.php/StartPage</base>
    <generator>MediaWiki 1.15.5-1~bpo50+1</generator>
    <case>first-letter</case>
    <namespaces>
      <namespace key="-2">Media</namespace>
      <namespace key="-1">Special</namespace>
      <namespace key="0" />
      <namespace key="1">Chat</namespace>
      <namespace key="2">user</namespace>
      <namespace key="3">Chat user</namespace>
      <namespace key="4">domain.net</namespace>
      <namespace key="5">Chat domain.net</namespace>
      <namespace key="6">files</namespace>
      <namespace key="7">Chat files</namespace>
      <namespace key="8">MediaWiki</namespace>
      <namespace key="9">Chat MediaWiki</namespace>
      <namespace key="10">Model</namespace>
      <namespace key="11">Chat model</namespace>
      <namespace key="12">help</namespace>
      <namespace key="13">Chat help</namespace>
      <namespace key="14">category</namespace>
      <namespace key="15">Chat category</namespace>
    </namespaces>
  </siteinfo>
  <page>
    <title>Drush</title>
    <id>579</id>
    <revision>
      <id>1637</id>
      <timestamp>2012-05-25T14:51:51Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>admin</username>
        <id>1</id>
      </contributor>
      <comment>/* Install Drupal with Drush */</comment>
      <text xml:space="preserve">Drush is a command line utility.

=Install Drupal with Drush=
To install drupal with drush :
 drush site-install standard --db-url=mysql://username:pass@localhost/databasename

[[category:Drupal]]</text>
    </revision>
  </page>
  <page>
    <title>Memcache</title>
    <id>586</id>
    <revision>
      <id>1287</id>
      <timestamp>2012-02-12T17:43:32Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>admin</username>
        <id>1</id>
      </contributor>
      <comment>Do it under Debian</comment>
      <text xml:space="preserve">=Install=
==Debian==
===Memcache Server===
To install :
 aptitude install memcached

Read and change ''/etc/memcached.conf''.
===PHP5 / PECL===
Install memcache PECL :
 php5-memcache
or
 pecl install memcache

Restart Apache.

===Drupal===
* InstallMemcache module in Drupal.
* Change ''settings.php'' :
&lt;source lang=&quot;php&quot;&gt;
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/memcache/memcache.inc';
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'MemCacheDrupal';
$conf['memcache_key_prefix'] = 'site_prefix';
&lt;/source&gt;

Read : http://drupal.org/node/1131458


[[category:Linux]]

[[category:Drupal]]</text>
    </revision>
  </page>
</mediawiki>
```

**Optional task :** How can I convert "=" to `<h1>`, "==" to `<h2>`, space before start of line to `<pre>`, [[category:xyz]] to Tags, etc ... ?

Comment: While I understand that you are doing this within the context of a Drupal module, your question is really about XPath, and has nothing to do with Drupal. I call off-topic. Your "optional task" however, should be opened as a separate question. I could actually write up something on that myself. I'll try and find the time for that later. :)

Comment: I don't completely agree, as the Feeds module has its own logic on top of XPath, so perhaps it's borderline, but maybe not OT. As for the optional task, [Feeds Tamper](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) could probably be of use.

Comment: @Countzero : Thank you, I'll gonna test Feeds Tamper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Context should be : `//Mediawiki/page`,  Title field should be `title` and Text should be `revision/text`.

Comment: It work great, thank you !! I think it can help everyone who want to import XML content to Drupal.